Unsure why RAM usage in Firefox exceeded 32GB due to one specific tab
What had happened:
On Firefox (Version 132.0.2 (64-bit)), which is the latest update, opening a specific website link caused my RAM usage to go ballistic, exceeding the 32 GB of RAM I have available. The website is one of those wedding websites, <withjoy.com> to be exact*, and when viewing the gallery of pictures the couple posted, it causes my computer to become unusable because it exponentially increases RAM usage until I am forced to close the tab. It is likely an issue on the <withjoy.com> website side, but this led me to investigate:
I used the about:memory feature of Firefox to generate a memory report, after having closed the <withjoy.com> tab, and found the following part that confuses me:
Main Process (pid 2840)
Explicit Allocations

341.64 MB (100.0%) ++ explicit

Other Measurements

134,217,727.94 MB (100.0%) -- address-space
├──132,096,616.26 MB (98.42%) ── free(segments=660)
├────2,120,139.82 MB (01.58%) -- reserved
│    ├──2,097,122.83 MB (01.56%) ── mapped(segments=17)
│    └─────23,016.99 MB (00.02%) ── private(segments=4058)
└──────────971.86 MB (00.00%) -- commit
           ├──420.86 MB (00.00%) -- private
           │  ├──414.95 MB (00.00%) ── readwrite(segments=3986)
           │  ├────2.78 MB (00.00%) ── readwrite+stack(segments=115)
           │  ├────1.64 MB (00.00%) ── execute-read(segments=18)
           │  ├────1.48 MB (00.00%) ── readwrite+guard(segments=115)
           │  └────0.02 MB (00.00%) ── readonly(segments=3)
           ├──282.45 MB (00.00%) -- image
           │  ├──189.29 MB (00.00%) ── execute-read(segments=154)
           │  ├───74.82 MB (00.00%) ── readonly(segments=468)
           │  ├───16.16 MB (00.00%) ── writecopy(segments=81)
           │  ├────2.18 MB (00.00%) ── readwrite(segments=208)
           │  └────0.01 MB (00.00%) ── noaccess(segments=3)
           └──268.55 MB (00.00%) -- mapped
              ├──200.38 MB (00.00%) ── readonly(segments=249)
              ├───54.84 MB (00.00%) ── noaccess(segments=99)
              ├───13.05 MB (00.00%) ── readwrite(segments=292)
              ├────0.28 MB (00.00%) ── writecopy(segments=1)
              └────0.00 MB (00.00%) ── execute-read(segments=1)

What is this address-space, and why is it so incredibly large? Currently allocated at approximately 134 TB:
134,217,727.94 MB (100.0%) -- address-space
├──132,096,616.26 MB (98.42%) ── free(segments=660)

The Firefox docs does not contain any information regarding this value in address-space, and I am curious if maybe this is the culprit? Or at least a symptom of what the <withjoy.com> site was doing wrong?
I would like to understand what is going on/going wrong.
The only add-on being used is Adblock Plus, and even disabling it did not make a difference.
* - Unfortunately I cannot share the exact tab as it is password protected for the specific wedding.
EDIT 1: Added link of other person with exact same reported value
I found this person on reddit reporting the exact same value Reddit-post seven years ago.

"Currently allocated at approximately 134 TB" Regardless of RAM, I doubt you have that much storage space available. Something else must be happening, this can not be a real value.

I agree, @Mast, that value makes no sense, but it is the only clear 'anomaly' that I could see in the report. I am hoping someone might know what that means. I am not the only person to have had this exact value reported, as I will link in an edit now.
